# Аналитика мобильных приложений

Tags: windowsphone, android, аналитика, ios, blackberry

Уважаемые участники ХэшКода, мне было бы очень интересно узнать о вашем опыте использования следующих инструментов, используемых для аналитики мобильных приложений:

1. [TestFlight/FlightPath](https://testflightapp.com)
2. [Flurry analytics](http://www.flurry.com)
3. [HockeyApp](http://hockeyapp.net)
4. [Google analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/)
5. Ваш вариант, о котором я не знаю

Меня интересует все, что связано со словом аналитика, интересуют аналитика для обеих фаз: и тестирования и продакшна, интересует, что измеряете и советуете измерять лично вы - советы, рекомендации, удачные находки итп.

Также как я делаю это во всех других моих вопросах, подчеркну, что буду признателен за развернутые ответы, содержащие реальный опыт, - например, вы предпочли один из инструментов взамен другого, или не порекомендовали бы использовать такой-то или..., словом реальный "живой" опыт!

И также как и во всех других своих вопросах, я обещаюсь опубликовать свой собственный ответ, когда решу, что достаточно созрел для того, чтобы сделать его качественным.

P.S. Несмотря на то, что моя платформа - Apple/iOS, я буду очень рад услышать и мнение представителей любых платформ.

Спасибо.

---

До тех пока я сам внятно не разобрался с аналитикой, буду пока просто постепенно формировать список инструментов для аналитики:

1. [TestFlight/Flightpath](https://testflightapp.com)
2. [Flurry analytics](http://www.flurry.com)
3. [HockeyApp](http://hockeyapp.net)
4. [Google analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/)
5. [Countly](http://count.ly/)

---

Новости про аналитику:

21 февраля, 2014 - [TestFlight Owner Burstly Acquired By Apple](http://techcrunch.com/2014/02/21/rumor-testflight-owner-burstly-is-being-acquired-by-apple/) и [Apple Buys TestFlight, Android Support Discontinued](http://www.infoq.com/news/2014/02/apple-buys-testflight).

Comment: @Gorets, его многие используют для доставки промежуточных сборок, и они ориентируются именно на мобильные платформы, а следовательно менее универсальные, что в свою очередь влечет больше возможностей.


@Stanislaw, на текущем проекте будем использовать как раз TestFlight для аналитики, так что смогу поделиться опытом, но немного позже.

Answer (score 1):

Попробовали TestLight - совсем не то, потому как неудобно смотреть статистику, там только пошаговое описание событий, есть у них еще [FlightPath](https://testflightapp.com/flightpath), судя по всему более заточенное под эти нужды, но оно в закрытой бете...

Пробовали Google Anal ytics - показался слишком монструзоным, нужен чуть не инженер чтоб собирал стату, т.е. не очень френдли для клиента.

Сейчас остановились на [MixPanel](https://mixpanel.com/), выглядит сочно, но опять таки только пробуем)

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, уточнить, почему TestFlight оказался не тем, что надо?

Comment: @Stanislaw, обновил ответ

Answer (score 1):

Мы использовали TestFlight раньше для дистрибуции билдов и креш репортов, все просто и удобно. Но где-то месяц назад перешли на Ubertesters - http://ubertesters.com/ , потому что кроме всего того, что дает TF, они еще предоставляют массу инструментов для организации процесса бета тестирования - например, можно сабмитить баги прямо с моб девайса с полной инфой и скринами, импортировать баги в сторонний баг трекер, также можно записывать сессии каждого тестировщика. Вообщем очень удобный сервис с массой полезных фич. На голову выше остальных продуктов, которые представлены на рынке.
А сейчас еще и новости о прекращении поддержки Android TF-ом, так что мы не расстроились особо )

Comment: Виктория, спасибо за ответ. Очень интересно.

Comment: Очень похоже на рекламный пост, но спасибо :)

Comment: Все кстати, наверное, уже в курсе, что Apple вроде как приобрела TestFlight? (я закинул пару ссылок в свой вопрос в качестве "новостей")